# Smooth CSS animation in reverse

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I recently came across [GotoMeeting's website](http://www.gotomeeting.com/online/) and I was very taken with the animated footer that slides away after you scroll down a bit. I wanted to re-create it myself and I mostly have it working. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7L9boyf/2/). The issue I have is that when you scroll up it 'snaps' into place rather than animating back up. What can I do to fix that?

Here is my code as well.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        width:100%;
        height:1600px;
        margin:0;
      }
      #bar {
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:gray;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes slideout {
        0% {
          -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
          transform:translateY(0);
        }
        100% {
          visibility:hidden;
          -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);
          transform:translateY(100%);
        }
      }
      @keyframes slideout {
        0% {
          -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
          transform:translateY(0);
        }
        100% {
          visibility:hidden;
          -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);
          transform:translateY(100%);
        }
      }
      .slide-down {
        -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
        -webkit-animation-name:slideout;
        animation-duration:3s;
        animation-fill-mode:both;
        animation-name:slideout;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes slidein {
        0% {
          visibility:visible;
          -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
          transform:translateY(-100%);
        }
        100% {
          -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
          transform:translateY(0);
        }
      }
      @keyframes slidein {
        0% {
          visibility:visible;
          -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
          transform:translateY(-100%);
        }
        100% {
          -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
          transform:translateY(0);
        }
      }
      .slide-up {
        -webkit-animation-duration:6s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both: -webkit-animation-name:slidein;
        animation-duration:6s;
        animation-fill-mode:both: animation-name:slidein;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onScrollBody() {
        var doc = document.documentElement;
        var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
        document.getElementById("scrollinfo").innerHTML = top;
        if (top > 200) document.getElementById("bar").className = "slide-down";
        else if (top < 200) document.getElementById("bar").className = "slide-up";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onscroll="onScrollBody()">
    <div id="bar">
      <p>TRY FOR FREE</p>
      <p id="scrollinfo"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're just animating a single property from 0% to 100%, I would simply recommend using `transition` which will automatically animate a property when it changes its value. That way, you simply need to add/remove a single CSS class that sets a new value and the change will animate as you want it to.

I updated so you can see what I mean:

```js
window.onscroll = onScrollBody;

function onScrollBody() {
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
    document.getElementById("scrollinfo").innerHTML = top;
    if (top > 200) document.getElementById("bar").className = "slide-down";
    else if (top < 200) document.getElementById("bar").className = "";
    //var nYScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
    //document.getElementById("scrollinfo").innerHTML = nYScroll;
    //if (nYScroll > 200) document.getElementById("bar").className = "slide-down";
    //else if (nYScroll < 200) document.getElementById("bar").className = "slide-up";
}
```

```css
body {
    width:100%;
    height:1600px;
    margin:0;
}
#bar {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}
.slide-down {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);
    transform:translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="onScrollBody()">
    <div id="bar">
        <p>TRY FOR FREE</p>
        <p id="scrollinfo"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```